# typeError: Cannt read property 'goBack' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, navigation

So the scenario is, I want to implement a GoBack Icon at the top of my app,that leads back to previous page. I am using stack navigator and disabled the header. So I need a go back button. I decided to make a component for that, here is my code,

```
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

function GoBack(){
    return (
        <Ionicons onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()} name="md-arrow-back" size={24} color="#0c85f3" />
    );
  }

  export default GoBack;
```

if I do it like this then an it shows me a typeError: Cannt read property 'goBack' of undefined.but if I put onPress as props and implement the same line of code `onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()}` it works perfectly.

I can not apply onPress props everywhere. Its a app with a lot of screens. How do I apply it in the component itself? 
I think I am in lack of deep understanding of React navigation. Please help me understand the solution too.

Here is how I am using the GoBack Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import TestRoomtData from '../../../testData';
import HistoryCard from '../../../components/cards/historyUserCard';
import GoBack from '../../../shared/goBackButton';


class UserHistory extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{flexDirection:"row",}}>
            <GoBack />
            <Text style={styles.title}>History</Text>
            </View>

            <Text  style={styles.title01}>Past Patients</Text>

                <FlatList 
                    data={TestRoomtData}
                    renderItem={({item})=>([
                        <View>
                          <HistoryCard 
                              prescription={item.prescription}
                              diagnosis={item.diagnosis}
                              date={item.date}
                              source={{
                                uri: item.uri
                              }}
                              btnText01="More"
                              btnText02="Edit"
                              onPressBtn2={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit History') }/>

                        </View>
                    ]
                    )}
                    />
                    </View>





        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a functional component,

**First** : so you can't use `this.` ,
**Second** : you forgot to get `props`

```
function GoBack(props){  // <---- HERE
    return (
        <Ionicons 
            onPress={props.navigation.goBack}  // <---- HERE
            name="md-arrow-back" size={24} color="#0c85f3" />
    );
  }
```

Comment: I just tried this.. It still shows me the same error. @Vivek

Comment: @ZeedTanue It should be working , Try this : `onPress={props.navigation.goBack}` or `onPress={(props) => { props.navigation.goBack(null)} }`

Comment: Still the same error, I am editing my question about how I am using GoBack Icon:

Answer (score 0):

In functional component in react, you can't use `this` keyword to access props.
In the current situation you have to pass navigation prop in `GoBack`
something like this,

```
function Goback(props) {
  const { navigation } = props;
  return (
    <Ionicons 
      onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} 
      name="md-arrow-back" 
      size={24} 
      color="#0c85f3" 
    />
   );
}
```

Now, call the GoBack component,

```
<GoBack 
  navigation={{ goBack: () => goBack() }}
/>
```